# LINQ, EF, Does one need a must to other in .net applications

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

1. To use LINQ, is it a *MUST* to use the Entity Framework in .Net applications?.
2. If we use Entity Framework in a .net application, **should** **we need to use** LINQ to query the databases?. Can't we use the normal SQL with Entity Frame Work?

Comment: What's the point in using Entity Framework if you (only) want to use SQL?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. To use LINQ, is it a MUST to use the Entity Framework in .Net applications?.

No. LINQ can be used for querying collection of objects, there are "LINQ to SQL" where you can query database without Entity Framework, there are LINQ to Xml where you can querying Xml structures like `XDocument` or `XElement`. [LINQ: .NET Language-Integrated Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)

> 2. If we use Entity Framework in a .net application, should we need to use LINQ to query the databases?. Can't we use the normal SQL with
>      Entity Frame Work?

Entity Framework support possibility to send manually created sql queries. [Entity Framework Raw SQL Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx)